# Angular: get the request header options of my current activated route in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, http-headers

I want to access the current routes request headers in my UI application,
previously i did it with this.route.queryParams as the parameters were being sent through URL now it will be sent via request headers.

how to achieve this??

need help

this is what i am currently doing

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
this.<something>= params['<something>'];
});
```

but what i need is when a request comes to my application,
i want to access the requestHeader in Angular and access the parameters of request header.

I tried this method below:

i Tried the following way but it return me a reference error as " reference error: Observe is not defined

```
this.http.get<any>(this.config.baseUrl + this.config.schemaName +"/login", 
{observe: 'body'})
.subscribe(resp => {
debugger;
resp.headers.add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "AUTH-TOKEN, X- Custom") 
console.log(resp.headers.get('AUTH-TOKEN'));
});
```

Comment: do you have an error message ? if yes, share it with us, otherwise try first